# How can i display a Right and Wrong sign without using images

Tags: html, css

i am working on asp.net mvc 3 web application and i need to view a green Right sign and red Wrong sign inside my application without using images so is this possible?, as i have note on some web site they use different kind of signs but u can not downloaded as an image som this means thay are being displyed as text or using Java script ...?
BR

Comment: what do you mean by green right and red wrong sign? what is relation with mvc? can you specify your question and give an example?

Comment: You can accomplish that using css 3. So there are actually css alternatives for images icons.

Comment: What is right and wrong is relative. The symbols used for them are culturally dependent, too, and often mentioned as prime examples of culture and country dependent ITC elements. My teachers at school used “✔” to mark *errors*. So unless you know that your audience will be of restricted cultural variation, it’s better to use words or abbreviations, and in any case explain any special symbols you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, not all browsers [support special characters](http://www.justwondering.co.nz/special-html-characters/) like this but you could easily output the follow and have it work in most cases:

```
<p class='right'>&#10004;</p>
<p class='wrong'>&#10006;</p>
```

Related css:

```
.right { 
 color: green;   
}
.wrong {
 color: red;   
}
​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaUaf/

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, then you mean that using &#10004 & &#10006 will be better than using Unicode Dingbats .. BR#

Comment: This would be my choice, if using images is simply out of the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at Unicode Dingbats if you want to avoid images

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat

For example:

✔
✖

You can then just use CSS to apply an appropriate color.

Test them on browsers your user base is likely to use to make sure they render correctly (not all browsers support all Unicode characters).

Comment: Testing in one’s own system does not reveal the font situation across computers. For example, “✔” is probably not available on Windows systems unless Microsoft Office software (which comes with Arial Unicode MS) has been installed; see font coverage info at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/ if you want to avoid images.

Comment: Very cool.  However, requires CSS3 (e.g. won't work in IE7 and earlier, which is still strangely common)